# Field must only contain letters. How to do this with Rails ActiveRecord Validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with a rails app and the project required the firstname and lastname fields of the User model to only accept letters.

How do you do this in Rails ActiveRecord validation?

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the conversation in the comments that's without an answer attached, the following should be what you're after:

```
LETTER_REGEX = /\A\p{L}+\Z/.freeze

validates :lastname, format: { with: LETTER_REGEX, message: "only allows letters" }
```

I'd recommend [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) if you're trialling different approaches. It lets you test input, and provides a good explanation of the regex. Here, for this example:

> ```
> \A asserts position at start of the string
> \p{L}+
>   matches any kind of letter from any language
>   + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> \z asserts position at the end of the string
> ```

Re `\p`, in this case it's taking a Unicode variant (all of which [can be viewed here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category), and in far more detail [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)).

Hope that's useful - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

RTM: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Will be something like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  LETTER_ONLY_RE = /\A\p{Letter}+\z/

  validates :lastname, format: { with: LETTER_ONLY_RE,
    message: "only allows lowercase letters" }
  # same for firstname

end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Austio. Must be something wrong here, it broke my routes.

Comment: `^` matches at the beginning of *line*, not *string*, you almost always want `\A` in Ruby. Similarly for `$`, you almost always want to use `\z` instead. Also, you're limiting yourself to ASCII, you might want to use `\p{Letter}` or one of the other Unicode-aware patterns instead.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for commenting. Please post an answer on how to do that.